# Undoing branch creation in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

How can I undo the creation of a branch in Mercurial? For example, if I issue the command

```
hg branch newbranch
```

How can I delete this branch if I decide I entered the wrong name? I'm guessing this must be pretty simple to do, but I have yet to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

if you haven't committed anything to it, it wasn't really created. so just issue another `hg branch newname`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I have committed the branch then. Oops. That I can resolve. Thanks for a quick solution anyway! This is still helpful.

Comment: in that case i don't think you can since the branch name is part of the revision. if it's that important you could `hg strip` the branch and do it all over again :)

Comment: Boo!  You shouldn't suggest `strip` without including a warning about the serious and severe risks in the case that other folks have already pulled the repo.

Comment: You said if you have not committed it wasn't really created, what if i don't want a branch at all, can I just continue or will my next commit include this branch as a commit?

Answer (score 51):

If you haven't committed yet, you can simply do a clean reset as per the manual (http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commands):

```
hg branch -C
```

This will reset the working directory's branch name to the parent of the branch that you just created.

Comment: Just mistakenly created a branch without committing and `hg branch -C` is clearly the way to go.

Comment: This best answers the question raised in the title.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

If its already commited:

- `hg clone -b branch1 [-b branch2 [-b ..]] oldrepo newrepo`, i.e. every branch except newbranch, will result in new repo without the newbranch.
- If mq extension is enabled then `hg strip`

Look into [editing history](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory) before making permanent changes in repository.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have not pushed to a remote repository, enable the mq extension and [strip](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Strip) the branch off.